# Unknown Error for File Picker in IOS Simulator

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-storage, maui

I am trying to build an app that uploads and retrieves images from a Firebase Storage bucket.

The issue is when I try to upload a file it says in the file picker in the IOS simulator the following error: Content Unavailable. The folder contents could not be displayed because of an unknown error. Check also the image below.

I have even downloaded the images and made sure they are in the Photos.

What I have also tried is updating the Info. list with the following:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your reason for accessing the photo library</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your reason for accessing the microphone</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your reason for accessing the camera</string>
```

[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jox5W.png)

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="fbStorage.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Pick and Upload" Clicked="OnUploadButtonClicked" />
        <Image x:Name="displayImage" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Firebase.Storage;

namespace fbStorage;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    

    //File Picker below
    async void OnUploadButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileResult result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
            if (result != null)
            {
                Stream stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                await UploadFileToFirebaseStorage(stream, result.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    async void DisplayImageFromFirebase(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream stream = await GetFileFromFirebaseStorage(filename);
            displayImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    async Task UploadFileToFirebaseStorage(Stream stream, string filename)
    {
        var storage = new FirebaseStorage("link");

        var imageRef = storage.Child("images").Child(filename);

        var task = imageRef.PutAsync(stream);
        task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
        };

        await task;

        DisplayImageFromFirebase(filename);
    }

    async Task<Stream> GetFileFromFirebaseStorage(string filename)
    {
        var storage = new FirebaseStorage("link");

        var imageRef = storage.Child("images").Child(filename);
        
        var downloadUrl = await imageRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
        
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(downloadUrl);
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions that you need to be attentive to.

1. You should replace the [File picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=macios) with [Media picker for photos and videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?tabs=macios) if you want to select an image in **Photos**.
2. Per error message below,

> Content Unavailable. The folder contents could not be displayed
> becuase of an unknown error.

This is due to there is no content to display on the simulator. You can try opening the **Photos** app in the simulator, then selecting an image, clicking the left-bottom share button, and choosing **Save to Files**. After saving the photo, you can run your app and choose this photo from the file picker. (Make sure you go to **Browse** tab and select the photo from the saved path.)

3. To access the `FilePicker`, you should enable [iCloud capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?tabs=vs#icloud). Please add an [Entitlements.plist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?tabs=vs#add-an-entitlementsplist-file) file, then check `iCloud` and `iCoud` Documents service.